# Images doesn't show

Tags: c#, asp.net, lightbox

I'm having trouble showing a list of images on a site.

using this question [How do you display a list of images, from a folder on hard drive, on ASP.NET website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629723/how-do-you-display-a-list-of-images-from-a-folder-on-hard-drive-on-asp-net-web)

ive pretty much just copied the answer as it is what i want to do. But, i end up with a bunch of nothing.
i've checked the page source in ´the browser and the image urls look correct

IE.

```
<a id="MainContent_RepeaterImages_Image_78"><img src="C:\Users\k\Galleries\Photos%20from%20the%20Final%20Conference\IMG_5962.jpg" alt="" />
```

code behind:

```
string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("Galleries") + "\\Photos from the Final Conference");

            List<String> images = new List<string>(filesindirectory.Count());

            foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
            {
                images.Add(String.Format("~/Images/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item)));
            }

            RepeaterImages.DataSource = images;
            RepeaterImages.DataBind();
```

and the asp:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="test">
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterImages" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

any ideas on what i'm missing?

Comment: Redid it after reading the two answers saying that that is how it works, and it does. I could swear I tried the exact same thing before posting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use relative paths to files stored within, or under the root of the application (that is, that web application's virtual directory (root folder)).

Using full, physical file names will only ever work (to my knowledge) in cases where the web-page file itself has been opened locally using the `file:///` protocol (and the 'urls' may need to comply, too). And I don't think I've ever come across a reason or need to do so - because relative paths will work either way.

Also, the code seems contradictory: you have a primitive HTML element (`img`) defined with a presumably hard-coded path value (given that you can't update non-server-side controls in the natural way from code as you would with server-side controls - unless maybe I'm getting confused with how it is rendering your `HyperLink` from the repeater.) The code you show which generates paths prefixes them with `~/images`, but this doesn't appear in the previously mentioned path - are you sure this is an exact representation of the result of the shown code? You would generally need to map the path to get such an output, and it wouldn't be likely to dismiss part of the specified path.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence of the accepted answer says:

> First you need to place the images you want to display under the web tree.

It won't work unless the images are in a folder within your web application's folder.

Note that the 2<sup>nd</sup> answer notes this too.

---

If you really want to use physical paths, then use the file:/// method as Mr. Disappointment notes (be aware it needs to be a local path (for the client) though and i'm not 100% sure if this works in all browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Probably your path may be referencing incorrectly, try to use  `Server.MapPath()`

Please have a look at this documentation about [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)