# Access all dropbox images in a public dropbox folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, api, dropbox

I would like to embed a photo gallery in my website that draws from a public dropbox folder. I can access a single image by referencing its public url as shown below:

```
//html of image on my page
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
//code behind setting image url
Image2.ImageUrl = "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/upfkqg2xlm6jjwc/-inOrlDJH0/star%20wars.jpg?m";
```

This works great for individual images, but I want to get all the images in a public folder. I have a public folder here loaded with two sample images, but I have been unable to use the api or other methods to get all contained files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/upfkqg2xlm6jjwc/bRiI4_tThF
I am looking for some way to load all contained files into a list of some sort.

Comment: Look at the answer on this stackoverflow posting- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629723/how-do-you-display-a-list-of-images-from-a-folder-on-hard-drive-on-asp-net-web perhaps this will work for you.

Comment: It's a dropbox folder, not a hard drive.

Comment: I haven't used the dropbox API, but can you not use: https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox/MyPublicFolder? Obviously you'd have to authenticate first, and as I'm not a dropbox user, I can't test it. But that would be the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to utilize what Pete stated into your application; or you'll have to input a link to in your application an extract the metadata through [JSON](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#files-GET). They have a few different API Examples in other languages; except I can't test because I don't use DropBox.  Here is an example from a blog that addresses some of those questions I hope it [helps](http://cgeers.com/2012/01/08/dropbox-rest-api-part-2-api-requests/).