# How to find the number of Images in a folder in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am new to Programming. So please guide me. I need to find that how many number of Images are available in a specific folder in ASP.net. then i need to bring all the images into a div using ajax like auto refresh when adding more images.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        innerDiv.className = 'pics';
        GalleryPics.appendChild(innerDiv);

        $(".pics").each(function (i) {
            i =i+1;
            $(this).append("<li><a href='../../uploads/" + i + ".jpg' width='300px' height='300px' rel='prettyPhoto[gallery]'><img src='../../uploads/" + i + ".jpg' width='160' height='160' /></a></li>");
        });
    });
</script>


<div class="col-md-12" id="GalleryPics">
<div class="pics"></div>
<div class="pics"></div>  
<div class="pics"></div>  
<div class="pics"></div>                      
</div>
```

In above divs, i have put the class name called "pics",i need to create the div also dynamically, but now i dont know to find the number of images available in the folder, so i couldnt make the corresponding div for the images.. So first i need to find the number of files available and then i need to auto refresh the div id="GalleryPics" to get all the images from the folder without refreshing the whole page.. Please response as much as you can.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Will all images always have numeric integer file names, serial? If you can depend on this (e.g. 31.jpg is last and there is no 32.jpg) you can do it all with client side scripting, let me know and I'll elaborate.

Comment: Is _[this what you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2629921/2260614)_ are trying to do..?

Comment: @RonniSkansing the lack of existing ASP.NET code does not mean the OP doesn't want a solution in ASP.NET, removing that information invalidated an answer and two comments.

Comment: @Stijn If the OP wanted a .asp answer he/she should should have added a minimal coded example with asp. Unless this is a "write the code for me" service. If a asp.net answer was approriate the OP should have shown a mimimal understanding what he/she was trying to solve. Now that you reverted the edit, you invite more "write-me-code" or perhaps you disagree, anyway I would like to know, so I do not edit such again.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Please elabarote me.. I dont have idea on this.. If i have files with alphabetic file names, what can i do..? tell me that too..

Comment: @user3336631 sorry, if the file names are not serial it won't work. What I had in mind is loop the files until you hit a nonexistant image, using the `onload` and `onerror` events.

Comment: Let it be.. I will tell you the whole scenario of my task that i need to upload the images in a specific directory, then i need to show all the images in a div on the same page which i have uploaded and also it should be auto refresh functionality.. So what can i do to achieve the following?
1.I have finished the upload part, so i can upload the images now.. but i need to retrieve all the images to a div in the same page.     2. I should make that div in Ajax to refresh itself for every 5 seconds

Comment: @RonniSkansing The correct action here then is to flag/close the question instead of removing tags.