# Foreach loop on images in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, loops

I am new to Asp.Net & C#. I am developing a blog. I am able to save images in a folder and the image path in SQL Server. Now I want to retrieve the image from folder whose path is stored in SQL Server table.

I try this:

**ASPX markup**:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="page-header"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">

        <asp:Image ID="Image1" CssClass="img-thumbnail" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>

</body>
```

**Code-behind**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Admin_Panel
{
    public partial class Admin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stuconnection"].ConnectionString);
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string qry = "SELECT * FROM upload";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
            SqlDataReader dr;

            con.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var filep = dr.GetString(1);
                Image1.ImageUrl ="~/Images/" + filep;
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

But the above code will only show one image.

**What I want:**  I want to show all images using a `foreach` loop or something like a loop, but I don't know how to do that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2629921/5268548

Comment: For this you need a repeater so that you can repeat your Image n number of time while loop is no good as you have one image control every time you loop you are binding different images for same control and the last item will bind the image control when loop ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should use asp.repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptImages" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Else:

```
public partial class Admin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<String> images = new List();      
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stuconnection"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string qry = "SELECT * FROM upload";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
           var filep = dr.GetString(1);
           images.add(String.Concat("~/Images/", filep);
        }
        con.Close();
        RptImages.DataSource = images;
        RptImages.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @arturas, Your code addition will solve the issue. can you please explain a little bit that what is going on, so I can understand it properly.

Comment: It's simple. in asp.net you can use asp.repeater in these cases, which has to be bounded with some datasource. 
We created list of image url's and then bounded it.